# Where can I deploy R script and schedule to run it in a timely manner?

Tags: r, twitter, shiny

I have a small `R` script. Typically, 15-20 lines of code. This script replies to random people on `Twitter`. Everything is working fine when I run the code. Now, I want to auto-run this after fixed intervals of time. So, I made a `.bat` the file of the `R` script and schedule the task in the windows scheduler to run after every 15 mins. This works fine as well and the way I expect it to work. Now, the problem is the scheduler works only when my system is working. Once I shut down my system, the scheduler also stops working and the script does not execute.

I want a server (not sure if this is the right word), where I can host the `R` file or `.bat` file and where I can schedule the script to execute after every X mins. I need a server (??) because I want this to be active 24 X 7.

I have tried deploying it on `shinyapps.io` but somehow it doesn't work. Have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309236/options-for-deploying-r-models-in-production) as well, with no help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: one suggestion would be to hire a amazon aws compute instance, and run your Rscript in a cronjob, but this assumes some knowledge of linux. Not sure what you have tried on shinyapps.io, but I assume that you want to use some sort of timeout to trigger a refresh of some `observe()` action, where the interior of the `observe()` calls the twitter API.

Comment: e.g, have a variable that auto increments every X minutes, have an observer for that variable, so that when it auto increments it does stuff.

Comment: rhcloud is free for micro instances.

Comment: @Alex and @ Neal - I'll try the suggestions given by you. Thank you.

Comment: if you can give us some example code we might be able to give you a working example which polls twitter data for example.