# Using a trained model in R on another language

Tags: r, node.js, machine-learning

I've trained a model using R, but now I am trying to deploy it in the current stack using NodeJS, I know that the model can be store as an RDS, but I'm not sure if I can use this model externally. Has anyone done this?

Comment: Related discussions [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-code-in-production-options/2015) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22309236/324364). The latter is fairly old, but based on SO conventions also probably dangerously close to a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are 2 answers.

The general case:

1. No, this is not only data represented in an R format (.RDS) it's also only really a "model" when it's being interpreted by not even just R, but the R library running on R that trained the model (`stats`, `caret`, `optimr`, etc). So [you could](https://github.com/joshkatz/r-script) launch R from another language [like NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-call-r), but it will still need to hit R at some point in the process.

and the exception

2. If you [create](https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml) a [PMML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language) model in R, you could export it and read it in another language, as that's universal.

Comment: Great answer! However, these days, one should use the `r2pmml` package (https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml) for creating a PMML model in R, because it supports more model types, performs better and generates more correct/compact PMML documents.

Comment: @user1808924 Thanks! I will add the link to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can expose your model as a REST API and  call it from any language